# What is the metallic alloy used in camera cases?

Tags: metallurgy, alloys

What is the metallic alloy used in camera cases?

They are manufatured by what process?

[image]

Comment: duraluminum alloy is pretty common.

Comment: Are there machining marks anywhere?

Comment: An extremely common cheap solution for this sort of applications - cast metal where durability doesn't need to be superb, just okay-ish - is ZnAl - a zinc-alluminum alloy, both cheap, light and very friendly for casting, but not very durable. I can't say if camera bodies use it (with that price tag they really can splurge on something better) but it's so extremely ubiquitous I suspect this is the case, at least with the cheaper ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mass production complex shapes like that are usually cast, then the casting is machined where accuracy and good finish is required. Magnesium is a good candidate for casting and Googling around about cast camera casings it seems many if not most of them use magnesium.

This is the Samsung NX1 which is magnesium.
[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_alloy

Huh. Apparently magnesium is even lighter than aluminum. I did not know that.

Comment: Cast by injection mold.  Magnesium primary advantage is low density.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - MIM (metal injection moulding) is *very* different from Die Casting - MIM uses powdered metal which is later sintered into a mostly solid block, where Die Casting uses Molten Metal directly. https://redstonemanufacturing.com/metal-injection-molding-vs-die-casting/

Comment: It looks like this is HPDC (high pressure die casting), but I'm only judging from the photo - I haven't researched specifically.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Well in any case, I use the term "cast" loosely here just to say some form of mould is involved.

Comment: I meant die cast injection mold ; some use a ram or piston to pressurize the molten metal immediately as it fills the mold. Die castings do not generally have any machining done other than run thread taps into holes and trim gates and any flash.